# unique records by one column

Tags: sql

I have been working on this for a long time now and cant get the answer. 
I have a table with 4 columns. I need to return two of these columns, A and B.
However I need the data to be filtered by the first column A. A is not a primary key. How can I achieve this? If I can return all the columns its also ok, as long as the data is only filtered by column A.

```
A  B  C  D
1  e  f  r
1  e  f  r
1  e  k  t
2  c  f  r
2  c  f  r
3  l  f  r
```

This should return

```
A  B  C  D
1  e  f  r
2  c  f  r
3  l  f  r
```

Which query wil give me this result? Until now I have this but it does not work well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, FROM myTable WHERE C=f
```

Comment: What is the result for your query?

Comment: Why should A=1 return C=f and D=r? And tag DBMS

Comment: what about 1, a, k, t? why not? you need to establish a criterial

Comment: use `group by` for this

Comment: try ´select a, min(b), min(c), min(d) from table group by A´ if no important which b,c,d item was shown

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: How to decide which row to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Row_Number()` to rank the rows within each distinct `A` value, then get the first row of each.

```
SELECT
    a, b, c, d
FROM
    (SELECT
        a, b, c, d,
        Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b, c, d) rn
    FROM
        myTable) mt
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Comment: You are the master. This is the only one I got working! I had to make an adjustment for it to work properly: I changed "FROM myTable) mt" >>> "FROM myTable WHERE C='f') mt". Now it works perfectly. The problem that no one seems to understand is that if you use DISTINCT on more than one column than the query wil return way more rows and they wil not be distinct. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT A,B FROM myTable WHERE C='f' GROUP BY A,B
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL 5.7, you also need to fix the SQL mode (`SET sql_mode = ''`) before this will work

Comment: this doesnt work. Maybe it will if aI set the sql mode. but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
with cte as 
(
select * , row_Number() over (Partition by A order by A) as aa from myTable
)
select * from cte where aa = 1
```

Comment: Yours work good as well. I had to make the same adustment as in Pete's code. Thanks!